# Remove or hide the "View" tab on a node

Tags: 7, routes

I know how to rename "edit" or "track" tab on user page and node page. Here's the code, it might help someone.

```
<?php

function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) {
//    drupal_set_message('Menu Items: <pre>'.print_r($items, TRUE).'</pre>');
    $items['user/%user/view']['title'] = "Profile";
    $items['user/%user/edit']['title'] = "Profile edit";
    $items['node/%node/edit']['title'] = "Node edit";

}
```

...but I don't know how to remove or hide the "View" tab on created node. 
my url page of the node is content/(node title).

What snippet should I use to remove the "View" tab on node page?

Comment: This question has been already answered on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530756/how-to-hide-edit-view-tabs

Comment: I think the view tabs don't appear if there is only one tab. So if you have devel enabled and have view and devel as tabs, the view will disappear when you disable devel.

Comment: I have two tabs. "View" and "Edit". I've renamed the second one, but I want to hide only "View" tab, so only "Edit" tab will be visible on node page.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this using css, or try using the code below or the [tab tamer](https://drupal.org/project/tabtamer) module

```
function MYMODULE_menu_alter(&$items) { 
  $items['node/%node/view']['access callback'] = 'MYMODULE_disable_node_view';
  $items['node/%node/view']['access arguments'] = array(1); 
} 

function MYMODULE_disable_node_view($node){
        return false;
}
```

Comment: I've tried the code and there's is one notice "Notice: Undefined offset: 0" and warning "Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()". It's for this line: **foreach ($data['tabs'][0]['output'] as $key => $value) {**

Comment: try the new update

Comment: I've tried the new code. It doesn't have any error and the "View" tab is hidden now. First I've checked with admin user, but with authenticated user there are no tabs on page node, so the edit tab is hidden too.

Comment: With your new code the view tab is hidden on both roles, but with authenticated user now the "Edit" tab is hidden too and that's why there are no tabs.

Comment: Does the authenticated user you used have permission to edit nodes?

Comment: Yes. Without your code the authenticated user has tabs "view" and "edit". I just only want to hide "View" tab and that's only on node pages, so only "Edit" tab on node page will appear.

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to hide the tab but maintain the access you could alter the menu callback type this way:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu_alter().
 */
function yourmodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  // Example 1: hide tabs on user/* for anonymous:
  $items['user/login']['type']    = MENU_CALLBACK;
  $items['user/register']['type'] = MENU_CALLBACK;
  $items['user/password']['type'] = MENU_CALLBACK;
  // Example 2:
  $items['user/%user/view']['type'] = MENU_CALLBACK;
  $items['user/%user/edit']['type'] = MENU_CALLBACK;
  $items['node/%node/edit']['type'] = MENU_CALLBACK;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your requirement is more of a presentation issue you could either use the hidden option in the [Tab Tamer Module](https://drupal.org/project/tabtamer) or a simple `css hide` hack.

If your requirement is related to user access then you could use the code hack for access callback or disabled option in Tab Tamer Module.

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 8: you can use hook_menu_local_tasks_alter

```
/**
 * Hide view tab from node edit.
 */
function MYMODULE_menu_local_tasks_alter(&$data, $route_name, \Drupal\Core\Cache\RefinableCacheableDependencyInterface &$cacheability) {
  if($route_name == 'entity.node.edit_form'){
    unset($data['tabs'][0]['entity.node.canonical']);
  }
}
```